# Replace chars order in string C#

Tags: c#, string

I have simple quesion but I have no idea how to solve it...

I have this string

```
RegisterDate = "25-05-2013";
```

I get this value via input. I want somehow to make this string be

```
RegisterDate = "2013-05-25";
```

My question is how could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: HAve you tried to google it first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: You can simply do a string.split on '-' and change the order...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want. Here I split the string into the three parts between the dashes, reverse it and then rejoin the parts again:

```
var registerDate = "25-5-2013";
registerDate = String.Join("-", registerDate.Split('-').Reverse());
```

If the string represents a date you can also use date parsing and formatting methods. Another option is to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Try to covert it to real date and convert it back again to string with your desired format.

```
RegisterDate = "25-5-2013";
DateTime _date = DateTime.ParseExact(RegisterDate, "M-d-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
RegisterDate = _date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: you have an error, the format should be d-M-yyyy. the string date isn't in US format

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I get this error message "The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context "

Comment: Press Ctrl+. and select one of the options. Or put `using System.Globalization;` in your source file.

Comment: This assumes that the string represents a date which probably is a safe assumption given the name `RegisterDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Use split: this way

```
string[] dateItems = RegisterDate.Split('-');
 RegisterDate = dateItems[2] + "-" +dateItems[1] + "-" + dateItems[0];
```